# Creating a map from an array of arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to write a function in Ruby which can take in a in an array of arrays, and convert it into a hash. This will be used to simulate sentences and create arbitrary word sequences. The resulting map will be helpful in generating all combination of sentences available with the current sentence rules.

How do I go about achieving this? I'm a bit lost as to where to start.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We'd like to see your attempt toward solving this, rather than a request for code. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)”. Currently your question is premature; Try, try, try some more, then ask a specific question about one part of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
arr = [ ["<start>", "The   <object>   <verb>   tonight."],   
        ["<object>", "waves", "big    yellow       flowers", "slugs"],   
        ["<verb>", "sigh <adverb>", "portend like <object>", "die <adverb>"],   
        ["<adverb>", "warily", "grumpily"] ]

arr.map { |ar| [ar.shift, ar.map { |str| str.split }] }.to_h
#=>
#{ "<start>"  => [["The", "<object>", "<verb>", "tonight."]],
#  "<object>" => [["waves"], ["big", "yellow", "flowers"], ["slugs"]],
#  "<verb>"   => [["sigh", "<adverb>"], ["portend", "like", "<object>"], ["die", "<adverb>"]],
#  "<adverb>" => [["warily"], ["grumpily"]] }
```

`ar.shift` takes the first element of each subarray. The block used with `ar.map` splits (on whitespace) the remaining elements into arrays. Finally `to_h` converts the resulting array into a hash.

Comment: Thanks, its working! Can you give a me a bit of an explanation of whats happening?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 I updated your answer. It's better in this way for me. Check if you like it ;)

Comment: @Ursus your latest update actually gave a different output, so rolled back.

Comment: [`Hash[ arr.map(&:shift).zip( arr.map{|x| x.map(&:split)}) ]`](https://repl.it/EJP0) also

Comment: This is aGood one!